# Consider a function defined on $\mathbb{R^2}$ by $f(x,y) = ....$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, continuity

Consider a function defined on $\mathbb{R^2}$ by

$$f(x,y) = 
\begin{cases} 0 &\mbox{if } y \leq 0 \ or \ \mbox{if} \ y\geq x^2 \\
sin(\frac{\pi y}{x^2}) & \mbox{if } 0 \ < y < x^2. \end{cases} $$

Show that the restriction of f to any straight line through the origin is continuous.

Attempt:

To me what that means is $y = \lambda x$ where $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$  Now if I attempt this I still arrive with an $x$ in the denominator and taking the limit of such will make my function go to $\infty$ which is not what we want. IS there another part of the condition I am not using? I was thinking that perhaps $0< \lambda < 1$. If that is the case how could I use it?

Comment: For any straight line through the origin, the line will go through the origin in the region where the function is defined as $0$.

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: It means that when you say "Now if I attempt this I still arrive with an $x$ in the denominator", that's wrong. You arrive with no denominators or sines or anything. You arrive at the origin with $0$, because for the part of the line closest to the origin, we do not have $0<y<x^2$.

Comment: @Arthur When you mention that, I drew out a graph of the domain and noticed that for $x < 1$, the condition to evaluate the function using the Sine function was not satisfied. Is there some "formal" way of writing this or is describing it in a paragraph form as above sufficient?

Answer (score 1):

First consider the case of restricting the function to the line $x=0$, call it $f_{\perp}(y)$. Since every point of this line satisfies the first condition we know that

$$ f_{\perp}(y)=0\text{ for all } y$$

so $f_{\perp}(y)$ is continuous.

Next, let $\lambda>0$ and define

$$ f_{\lambda}(x)=f(x,\lambda x)$$

Then

$$  f_{\lambda}(x)=\begin{cases}
0 & \text{if }x\le\lambda\\
\sin\left(\frac{\pi\lambda}{x}\right)&\text{if }x>\lambda
\end{cases} $$

So it is clearly continuous for all $x\ne\lambda$. So consider $x=\lambda$.

We have $f_{\lambda}(\lambda)=0$ and 
$$\lim_{x\to\lambda^-}f(x)=0\text{ and}  \lim_{x\to\lambda^+}f(x)=\sin(\pi)=0=f_{\lambda}(\lambda)$$
so the function is continuous at $x=\lambda$.

Comment: You have your inequalities backwards. $f_\lambda(x)=\sin(\frac{\pi\lambda}x)$ when $x\gt\lambda$, not when $x\lt\lambda$, because the condition $0\lt y\lt x^2$ becomes $\lambda x\lt x^2$ or, dividing by $x$, $\lambda\lt x$.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Oops! Thanks

Comment: Here is the correct solution after correcting the inequalities.